# How to make container with AutomaticNotchedShape effect

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to make this widget in a random container (its not in the bottomAppBar) , I know I can achieve this with CustomPaint(), but is there a easier way of doing it? Like a  AutomaticNotchedShape or something like it...

[image]

Comment: There is actually an AutomaticNotchedShape class! (https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/AutomaticNotchedShape-class.html). Not immediately sure yet how to use it outside of a BottomAppBar, though...